# yard inside garden detection (cv2)

Tags: python, image, colors, computer-vision, opencv

I want to seperate the gras thats inside my garden from the gras outside of it using the fence basement and the stones. The script should be able to draw the red line that you can see at the second image.
It should be possible with cv2

Ive tried a code that i found at a driving lane detection system, but unfortunately its not working good for gras.

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(gras_image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5,5), 0)
canny = cv2.Canny(blur, 50, 200)
```

[image: yard]

[image]

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

See the comments in my code below for how you can select just your yard in your image.

This won't be a robust solution if the color of the border between your yard and not your yard changes. I found a suitable HSV range by opening your image in GIMP and selecting the brown border object on the right side with GIMP's color picker tool. Miraculously this color also worked well for the gray blocks. You might be able to get better results by playing with the color ranges, or maybe even by creating separate masks for the brown blocks and the gray blocks.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

#load the image
image = cv2.imread("meadow.jpg")

#define the lower and upper bounds of colors to threshold for in the HSV color space.
hsv_lower = (35//2, 0, 120)
hsv_upper = (45//2, 255, 255)

#convert the image to HSV color space
hsv_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

#find the areas of the image corresponding to the colors set above
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_image, hsv_lower, hsv_upper)

#set the detected areas to white and other areas to black
new_image = np.where(mask, np.uint8(0), np.uint8(255))

#erode to fill in the gaps between the black pixels.
new_image = cv2.erode(new_image, kernel=np.ones((7,7)))

#find connected components (the white areas)
labels, stats = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(new_image)[1:3]

#create a mask for the area excluding the largest component
not_my_yard = labels != np.argmax(stats[:,cv2.CC_STAT_AREA])

#set the color of the area excluding the largest component to black
image[not_my_yard] = 0

#save the new image
cv2.imwrite("my_yard.jpg", image)
```

[image]

Comment: Sry, I forgot to add the picture without the imagined red line. The python script that i want should do that step. And it should be independent of the color of the grass, able to recognize the edge. Because the fence base and the rocks are good visible do you think it would be possible with cv2 canny() and HoughLinesP()?

Comment: I assumed you wanted to detect the border and not the color of the grass, which is why I chose the brown blocks. It looks like they are not as visible in your new image and this method might not work anymore. I don't think Canny or HoughLinesP will work for this. Try doing the same as what I did but creating a mask for your dark green fence and white bricks and combine the masks. Then use findContours instead of connected components. After finding the contours you can draw the border in red using drawContours. I will help later if I I can find some more time.

Comment: Do you know if there is a pattern finder that gets the color ranges of the gras and the fence? Why should i use HSV instead of the RGB here?

Comment: I don't know of an easy way to find the color ranges. If you want a more exact range then you could crop out the target section, load it up into a Python script, and get the min-max ranges for each channel (hue, saturation, value). You could use RGB instead of HSV if you want, but it will probably be quite a bit harder to find the right color range.

Comment: Is there a pattern detection system for gras concrete or other materials like that?

Comment: Probably not in the way that you are imagining. The closest thing available to that would be image segmentation, which will be rather difficult to implement. Google for "image segmentation" for more information and helpful guides.